I'm trying to make a simple rock-paper-scissors code
I've been trying to make a very simple rock-paper-scissors code with my very very limited knowledge of the C language.
Whenever I run the program, it doesn't print anything only until after I input the 2 numbers (1-scissors, 2-paper, 3-rock), and it also doesn't print the last statement.
Output:
1
3
Press 1 for scissors, 2 for paper or 3 for rock. 

Same for player two.

Code:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Press 1 for scissors, 2 for paper or 3 for rock. \n");
    int f;
    int h;
    scanf("%d", &f);
    printf("\nSame for player two.");
    scanf("%d", &h);
    if (f == h) {
        printf("Tie\n");
    }
    
    if (f == 1 && h == 2) {
        printf("Player 1 won\n");
    }
    
    if (f == 2 && h == 1) {
        printf("Player 2 won\n");
    }

    if (f == 2 && h == 3) {
        printf("Player 1 won\n");
    }
    
    if (f == 3 && h == 2) {
        printf("Player 2 won\n");
    }
    
    if (f == 3 && h == 1) {
        printf("Player 1 won\n");
    }
    
    if (f == 1 && h == 3) {
        printf("Player 2 won\n");
    }
    
    return 0;   
}

This is supposed to be a project only for my interest, I don't want to know a way on how an expert would make a rock-paper-scissors game, but to know what I did wrong for the code not to work as expected.
I was expecting a similar outcome to using cout<< and if commands in C++.

Read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? Please [edit] the question to post the code as plain text, and please also reformat it with proper indentations for easier reading.

As a general word of advice... Inconsistent use of indentation and other whitespace makes it difficult for people (including you) to read and understand your code.  Keeping your code easily readable will help you follow what it's doing.

In C++, cin and cout are tied together by default, thus reading input will automatically flush any pending output first. That is not the case in C.  Since you are not outputting a \n before the 2nd read, you need to manually call fflush(stdout), eg: printf("\nLa fel pentry jucatorul doi."); fflush(stdout); scanf("%d", &h);

What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?

Have you tried running your code line-by-line in a debugger while monitoring the control flow and the values of all variables, in order to determine in which line your program stops behaving as intended? If you did not try this, then you may want to read this: What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems? You may also want to read this: How to debug small programs?

Side note: always check the return value from scanf to ensure input was valid. Also, use an enum to give names to values rather than just using 1, 2, and 3 in your code. These don't convey any meaning.

I have the impression that you are not yet ready to create a rock-paper-scissors game. I recommend that you do some simpler assignments first, by doing a beginnner's course on C. If you like learning from videos and understand spoken English, then I recommend the free CS50x course. After completing week 1 of that course, you should be able to create a rock-paper-scissors game, but you may want to wait until after week 2. Alternatively, there are also some Beginner's level books for teaching C.

It looks like your IDE is trying to make your life miserable. Which IDE are you using? Try running your program in a standard OS terminal, not in an IDE.

According to §7.21.3 of the ISO C11 standard, the standard output stream is supposed to be automatically flushed when new input is requested. However, the ISO C standard does not strictly require this.
It appears that you are using a platform which does not follow these guidelines.
In order to fix this, you can explicitly call fflush(stdout) before any call to an input function, such as scanf.
